# Creating a dataframe by concatenating substrings of non-uniform lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, substring, variable-length

The raw data (.txt) file has 65926 elements, each containing a 142 character string.

Here's the [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/avtkxtf58k9hko6/R71252L01.TXT?dl=0) to the raw data file.

The task is to divide that 142 character string into 37 smaller strings (each substring being a separate character variable), each one beginning sequentially at following positions:
1,4,9,11,14,15,16,19,21,24,26,27,28,32,33,34,36,38,43,45,46,47,48,52,56,60,66,72,75,76,77,78,79,80,127,130,133

The final output must be a 65926 x 37 dataframe. Here's a snapshot of the output dataframe:

[image: Here's a snapshot of the output dataframe.]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
x <- readLines("R71252L01.TXT")
a <- c(1,4,9,11,14,15,16,19,21,24,26,27,28,32,33,34,36,38,43,45,46,47,48,52,56,60,66,72,75,76,77,78,79,80,127,130,133)
z <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(x), ncol = length(a)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for (i in 1:length(x) ) {
z[i,] <- (list(
            (c(substr(x[i], 1, 3),substr(x[i], 4, 8),substr(x[i], 9, 10),
               substr(x[i], 11, 13),substr(x[i], 14, 14),substr(x[i], 15, 15),
               substr(x[i], 16, 18),substr(x[i], 19, 20),substr(x[i], 21, 23),
               substr(x[i], 24, 25),substr(x[i], 26, 26),substr(x[i], 27, 27),
               substr(x[i], 28, 31),substr(x[i], 32, 32),substr(x[i], 33, 33),
               substr(x[i], 34, 35),substr(x[i], 36, 37),substr(x[i], 38, 42),
               substr(x[i], 43, 44),substr(x[i], 45, 45),substr(x[i], 46, 46),
               substr(x[i], 47, 47),substr(x[i], 48, 51),substr(x[i], 52, 55),
               substr(x[i], 56, 56),substr(x[i], 60, 65),substr(x[i], 66, 71),
               substr(x[i], 72, 74),substr(x[i], 75, 75),substr(x[i], 76, 76),
               substr(x[i], 77, 77),substr(x[i], 78, 78),substr(x[i], 79, 79),
               substr(x[i], 80, 126),substr(x[i], 127, 129),substr(x[i], 130, 132),
               substr(x[i], 133, 142)
            ) )
        )    )
i <- i+1
}
```

The code works but there are two issues:

1. The start and stop indices for `substr()` have to be manually typed out. Any way to utilize the vector `a` instead of all that manual labour?
2. The code takes over 30 minutes to execute. Checking time:

   ```
   > system.time(source('Hitesh_Script.R'))
       user   system  elapsed 
   4452.464    9.440 4476.018
   ```

   Can this be done faster?

I have to perform this task for several raw data files, each with a different vector `a`. Hence any other suggestions for efficiency will also be appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Comment: it would be great if you could share a small sample of "z" for us to work on!

Comment: In general, avoid using for-loops on large dataframes (`for (i in 1:length(x) )` or `for (i in seq_along(x) )`) if there is a vectorized alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just simulated a scratch data and shared a simple code

```
a <- c(1,4,9,11,14,15,16,19,21,24,26,27,28,32,33,34,36,38,43,45,46,47,48,52,
       56,60,66,72,75,76,77,78,79,80,127,130,133)
df = data.frame(
  x = c("uiagdsjgcjkh bijacydgasxdhsfkajdh,cnfwkeyrg,urnyhvguirwljbhgkjgjgdkgkdgkgdkgdkgdkgdkgdkgdkgdkdgkdgkdgkdgkjdgkdwjbiuayeiuy ke,ynh lgdiyl", 
        "kjhfkjsdlfkojjhgckjasnhjhckjsybsanhdsabtgchbtsjahasijhcndkuysefiuwyhsnidxjnkausetfba jwf,mycaiusftbbawubbctejdgkjdghjgdduiacwyftacbm"))
```

---

```
# > df
# x
# 1 uiagdsjgcjkh bijacydgasxdhsfkajdh,cnfwkeyrg,urnyhvguirwljbhgkjgjgdkgkdgkgdkgdkgdkgdkgdkgdkgdkdgkdgkdgkdgkjdgkdwjbiuayeiuy ke,ynh lgdiyl
# 2 kjhfkjsdlfkojjhgckjasnhjhckjsybsanhdsabtgchbtsjahasijhcndkuysefiuwyhsnidxjnkausetfba jwf,mycaiusftbbawubbctejdgkjdghjgdduiacwyftacbm
```

---

```
df1 <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) lapply(seq_along(a), function(i){
                                              if (i==length(a))
                                                substr(x,a[i],nchar(as.character(x)))
                                              else
                                                substr(x,a[i],a[i+1]-1)}
                                        )))
colnames(df1)=paste0("x",1:dim(df1)[2])

df1
#    x1    x2 x3  x4 x5 x6  x7 x8  x9 x10 x11 x12  x13 x14 x15 x16 x17   x18 x19 x20 x21
# 1 uia gdsjg cj kh   b  i jac yd gas  xd   h   s fkaj   d   h  ,c  nf wkeyr  g,   u   r
# 2 kjh fkjsd lf koj  j  h gck ja snh  jh   c   k jsyb   s   a  nh  ds abtgc  hb   t   s

#   x22  x23  x24  x25    x26    x27 x28 x29 x30 x31 x32 x33
# 1   n yhvg uirw ljbh gkjgjg dkgkdg kgd   k   g   d   k   g
# 2   j ahas ijhc ndku ysefiu wyhsni dxj   n   k   a   u   s

#                                               x34 x35 x36 x37
# 1 dkgdkgdkgdkgdkdgkdgkdgkdgkjdgkdwjbiuayeiuy ke,y nh  lgd iyl
# 2 etfba jwf,mycaiusftbbawubbctejdgkjdghjgdduiacwy fta cbm
```

Comment: Nice. What is the runtime? Is it faster with `stringi`?

Comment: @smci as the OP didn't share a sample data, i just ran on a very small data(2 obs only )!! so no point of running system.time() on this

Comment: This shows only the first 36 columns, the last one is missing for some reason. But runtime is only 2 seconds! Wow! Please help for that one last mile. Am not fully conversant with all these commands so will take a while to understand.

Comment: @90.hitesh please share a sample of your data so that I can run and compare the speed

Comment: @90.hitesh I have edited the answer. Please run on your data and you could share the output and time it took. I hope this answers your question well

Comment: @ joel.wilson Already shared data. But the job is done! Runtime is 2 seconds. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `readr` package (part of Hadley's *tidyverse*) offers an even faster solution to read and split the fixed width file in one rush.

The given sample file on dropbox took *0.17 sec elapsed time* on my system to read in and return the 65,926 × 37 data.frame.

```
library(readr)

a <- c(1,4,9,11,14,15,16,19,21,24,26,27,28,32,33,34,36,38,43,45,46,47,48,52,56,60,66,72,
       75,76,77,78,79,80,127,130,133)

z <- read_fwf("R71252L01.TXT", fwf_widths(diff(c(a, 142))),
              col_types = stringr::str_dup("c", length(a)))
```

Output is a *tibble*, an improved `data.frame`:

```
print(z, n = 3, width = Inf)

# A tibble: 65,926 × 37
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1   000 37773    71   252     1     1   012    05   005    01
2   000 37773    71   252     1     1   012    05   005    01
3   000 37773    71   252     1     1   012    05   005    01
    X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17   X18   X19   X20
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     2  0110     1     2    01    01 00000    01     1
2     1     2  0110     1     2    02    01 00000    01     1
3     1     2  0110     1     2    03    01 00000    01     1
    X21   X22   X23   X24   X25    X26    X27   X28   X29   X30
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1  <NA>  6538  4001  <NA> 120314 310314   115     2     2
2     1  <NA>  6538  4001  <NA> 120314 310314    90     2     2
3     1  <NA>  6538  4001  <NA> 130314 310314    90     2     2
    X31   X32   X33   X34   X35   X36   X37
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     2     2     2  <NA>     1     2 21433
2     2     2     2  <NA>     1     2 21433
3     2     2     2  <NA>     1     2 21433
```

### Explanations

- You can specify either field widths or start and end positions of fields. Computing widths from the given start positions `a` using `diff` required less coding. However, the end position (142) has to be specified any way.
- To stay in line with the Q, I forced all columns to be of type `character` with the parameter `col_types = stringr::str_dup("c", length(a))`. If the OP needs the columns to be of other types, this can be specified as required or rely on the built-in type recognition, see `help("read_fwf")`.
- I've also tried `read.fwf()` first but this is *magnitudes slower* (32.7 sec elapsed time).